# Subtracting seconds in Excel

Tags: excel, time

I'm trying to subtract start time from end time to get duration, ie:

```
1:02 - 0:10 = 0:52
```

But what I'm getting is:

> 0:92

I'm using the `0\:00` format. Other suggested formats, such as `[mm]:ss`, are turning my data into numbers that I don't undestand, ie `1:02` becomes `146880:00`

I just want to quickly enter a bunch of times, subtract one col from the other and be done with it.

Does anyone know a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions follow an explanation of the results showing in the question.

The format `0\:00` is really the format `000` with a colon character inserted between the first and second digits.

If a cell holds the value `102` and has a format of `0:\00` it will show as `1:02` in the worksheet but behind the scenes its value is still `102`. So

```
  1:02 - 0:10 = 102 - 10 = 92 = 0:92 in 0\:00 format
```

To understand the result with the `[mm]:ss` format, you need to understand how dates (and time) values are represented in Excel. There is a reasonable explanation [on this webpage from Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm)

First, as a date/time value `102` is equivalent to `0:00 on 11 April, 1900` as it is 102 days from Excel's day/time zero. Second, the format `[mm]:ss` expresses this elapsed time in minutes and seconds. So

```
102 days = 102*24*60 minutes = 146880 minutes
```

which gets displayed as `146880:00` in `[mm]:ss format`

There are a couple of ways you might resolve your problem.

The first involves entering data differently. A time can be entered directly into the worksheet as hours:minutes:seconds. So 1 minute and 2 seconds can be  entered as `0:1:2` (or `00:01:02` or any variant such as `0:01:2` or `00:1:02`). This is probably less convenient than just entering `102`. By default, numbers entered in this way will display in a `hh:mm:ss` format but you can suppress the display of hours by changing the format to `mm:ss` or `[mm]:ss`. The latter should be used if any of your time values are 60 minutes or more since, the former will suppress the display of hours - for example, entering `0:61:2` (61 minutes and 2 seconds) displays as `01:02` with the former but as `61:02` with the latter.

Note that if you just enter `1:2` rather than `0:1:2` Excel interprets this as 1 hour, 2 minutes and 0 seconds and will display as `02:00` using format `mm:ss` or as `62:00` using `[mm]:ss`.

The second way allows you to enter the data as before using the `0\:00` format but requires the use of formulae to convert your entered value into seconds - so, for example, an entered value of `102` is intended to represent 1 minute and 2 seconds, gets correctly displayed as `1:02` but is converted behind the scenes to `62` seconds.

If `A1` and `B1` contain the entered values the then formula for `A1 less B1` is

```
=(INT(A1/100)*60+A1 - 100*INT(A1/100))-(INT(B1/100)*60+B1 - 100*INT(B1/100))
```

This formula calculates its result as a number of seconds.

If this result is placed in cell `C1` then the formula

```
=100*INT(C1/60)+(C1-60*INT(C1/60))
```

converts `C1` to a result suitable for displaying with the `0:\00` format

Alternatively, the result in seconds can be converted to days by dividing by `24*60*60 = 86400` and displayed using a time format such as `[mm]:ss`